# How I Can Fetch YouTube Videos Through API?

Tags: node.js, google-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-nodejs-client

How I Can Fetch YouTube Videos Through API,
I Want To Fetch All Videos Of A Specific Channel By YouTube API,

But How Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) method

> Returns a collection of search results that match the query parameters specified in the API request. By default, a search result set identifies matching video, channel, and playlist resources, but you can also configure queries to only retrieve a specific type of resource.

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var youtube = google.youtube({
   version: 'v3',
   auth: "your-api-key"
});


youtube.search.list({
    part: 'snippet',
    q: 'your search query'
  }, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error: ' + err);
    }
    if (data) {
      console.log(data)
    }
  });
```